# Regex to restrict Chinese characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a novice in regex. I wan't the field to be only filled in English (I Don't want to allow any Chinese characters to be submitted)  So far I've come up with this:

```
<input type="text" id="FirstName" data-val-regex="Please fill out in english." data-val-regex-pattern="[A-Za-z \\u4E00-\\u9FFF\\u3400-\\u4DFF\\uF900-\\uFAFF ]+"  />
```

How can I omit numbers and also characters like ?,- (question mark, hyphen, comma etc)

In other words - the field should only allow alphabets with a space (this would be ideal for a name field I suppose?)

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Default regex patterns: `a-zA-Z` all alphabetic characters, `\d` any digit, `-` is a hyphen, and `\?` is a question mark.

Comment: By "restrict", do you mean the entire entry must be Chinese characters, or must **not** contain any Chinese characters, or...? Can you state clearly the criteria which you want to match? It might be helpful if you gave some examples which you would like to match or not match.

Comment: @torazaburo I've added  more details in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]+$
```

`^ ... $` - Mark string boundaries (start to end)

`[ ]+` - Match atleast one character of characters inside `[ ]`

Comment: This doesn't allow a space  between words anymore and doesn't show an error when a number is keyed in

Comment: @lily I misread your question. Those unicode ranges are completely unneccesarry. `a-zA-Z`(or `\w`, in this case) doesn't even allow chinese characters. I changed my regex, it should work for passwords like `cheese 12?-d` now.

Comment: I guess he **doesn't** want to allow dashes and question marks, nor the numbers and underscores that `\w` would allow.

Comment: That's right, the field should only allow alphabets with a space

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this attribute `data-val-regex-pattern` represent a regex that specifies what is allowed?  In that case wouldn't alphabet characters and a space suffice?

```
"[A-Za-z ]+"
```

Comment: If it were the HTML5 `pattern` attribute, it would not need `^` and `$` anchors, but if he has code which is handling the `data-val-regex-pattern` himself, it probably needs to be anchored, unless that code applies the anchors itself somehow.

Comment: @GantTheWanderer How can we ensure there is a space after every word? Because when I switch keyboards from Chinese to English, I'm unable to have a space between words.

Comment: Its hard to determine what you want to do when you say you _Don't want to allow any Chinese characters to be submitted_  then somehow need to switch to a Chinese keyboard at the same time.  Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry my bad, forgot to remove some JS code I was testing out previously.